# PowerBuilder and PHP

Tags: php, web, integration, powerbuilder

Please excuse my distinct lack of knowledge in this field. Software development is not my forte.

I am currently about to commence work on a project of which there is a large system built using PowerBuilder with an Oracle Enterprise database to serve the data up.

I want to build a nicer interface for the system and believe it is possible to use web technologies (my background) to do so. Can anyone confirm if it is possible to use PHP with PowerBuilder or is there a way in which I can interface my build with PowerBuilder?

Comment: Thanks for voting my answer. I thought of something else that might help. I'm not a PHP expert but I have used PHP/mySQL as backend for a PowerBuilder front end by using JSON. Basically have the PHP create JSON data, but ideally you'd want to create web services so that there is security and I don't know if that's possible in PHP. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a "good" way to incorporate PB & PHP but if there is a will there is always a way.

One unusual but possible way of mixing the technologies might be to write an IIS handler with PowerBuilder.NET, or you could build the handler using Visual Studio and call a PowerBuilder .NET Assembly from the handler. I find it is easier to build the handler using Visual Studio myself because I had problems getting PB.NET to inherit from HTTPHandler or using the .NET interface.  Doing this would be like re-inventing ASP.NET as it basically just processes .ASP files and kicks out HTML/Javascript/CSS,etc and you'd be writing a handler for a different file extension (say .pb or .powerbuilder) and spitting out your favorite web code based on what filename and/or arguments you used in the URL.

I made something like this not long ago just to see if I could do it and it wasn't too difficult. Eventually I'll post the code on my PB blog.  I've seen another implementation of something like this using CGI which is older technology, not as good as using a handler for busy sites.

Again this probably wasn't the answer you were looking for but it is an answer. Good luck.